# VBA button on source file to export specific columns from a specific row and paste to a target excel file with the same format/ style

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, vba

I'm a VBA noob trying to create an import button on an excel file that will check for the row count from another workbook and update the current file when there is a new row added to the other workbook. Any ideas how to do this please?

UPDATE:
I figured it would be better to export the contents from my source excel file rather than import from the target file.

If you have better options to have the same end result, other than what I did, I would appreciate it very much.

```
Sub Export2Report()

Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim row_input As Long
Dim lr As Long

'Set open target file
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

'Source sheet for data
Set sh1 = wb1.Sheets("sheet2")

'input row to be copied
row_input = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Row to Export", Title:="Range Select", Type:=9)

'select columns to copy
Union(Cells(row_input, 5), Cells(row_input, 6), Cells(row_input, 9), Cells(row_input, 10), Cells(row_input, 14), Cells(row_input, 15), Cells(row_input, 16), Cells(row_input, 17), Cells(row_input, 21), Cells(row_input, 22), Cells(row_input, 23), Cells(row_input, 24), Cells(row_input, 25), Cells(row_input, 28), Cells(row_input, 30)).Select
Selection.Copy

'open target report file
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\excel2.xlsm")
Set sh2 = wb2.Sheets("sheet2")

'activate target sheet and paste data to workbook 2
sh2.Activate
sh2.Unprotect Password:="xx"

Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'place borders on all cells

    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

wb2.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Please show the code what you have done and where you are going wrong. Try to code the problem !

Comment: updated question